# In Swift, How do I change the variable in function?

Tags: swift, function, swift2

I want to access stringEncoded in viewDidLoad but I cannot. How do I access it. Is it because it is not in main queue or is it about global variables staff?

I try new codes but still it doesn't work...

//Editted.

Comment: Can you the code here?

Comment: Where do you set deneme="batu"? in intiializer?

Comment: @SahilKapoor I added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code your provided, the `var stringEncoded` is defined into your `jsonGetir` function, while you want to access it from your `viewDidLoad`

So the solution is to put this variable in the class level, like this:

```
class YourClass{
    var stringEncoded = "asomthing" //change the value or the type to whatever suites u

    viewDidLoad{}
    func jsonGetir(){}
```

}

#### Update

As you requested, a full working example:

```
import UIKit


class StViewController: UIViewController {

    var stringEncoded = [String]()



    func jsonGetir() {

        let urls = NSURL(string: "http://gigayt.com/mackolik/deneme.php")

        let sessions = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urls!){

            data, response, error -> Void in

            if (error != nil){
                print(error)
            }

            do {
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    let x = jsonResult["kodlar"] as! String


                    self.stringEncoded = x.componentsSeparatedByString(",")


                }
            }

            catch {
                print(error)
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            }
        }

        sessions.resume()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for i in 0..<self.stringEncoded.count {
            print(self.stringEncoded[i])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can not understand it. Can you explain in more details?

Comment: I meant that you should put the stringEncoded as a class variable, as I did. Then you can use it anywhere you want.

Comment: But, the data I want to access is in the function. I cannot manipulate it as I want this way. What you are saying makes it like a global variable, I can use it but I can't change its values.

Comment: why you can't change its value? it is a property, you can read and write. You can call your function inside viewDidLoad as well

Comment: I don't know, can you test the code in your mac? If you test it, then you will understand me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested it please ?

Comment: thanks for everything but still it doesn't work. I updated my topic, and I added full of my codes. Can you see again??

Comment: what does *still doesn't work* mean ? kindly post the error message, post the line that makes the error, state why my solution didn't work though i tested it on my machine.

Comment: Initially, there was no error and it shows nothing in the run time. No compiler errors, and no run time errors. Can you test again my full code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90692/discussion-between-batuhan-kok-and-william-kinaan).

Comment: That is because you didn't call your function inside the viewDidLoad.

Comment: I refreshed my all codes. There was an error like this: ( use of unresolved identifier 'x' ) on this line (in viewDidLoad): var b = x.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

Comment: no body will read the whole code like that. Again I solved your initial problem, if you have another problem, post a new question, if my solution didn't work with you, post the error message that you got. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable in class scope.  If you want persist the that parameter then you can use **inout** parameter. Please refer to get more about **inout** parameter, hope you understand